# Angular2 FormBuilder and nested object property returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just getting my feet wet with TypeScript and Angular2. I'm working with an API that has a nested object structure. I would like my model to mirror the resource from the API. The model/resource, "Inquiry", as defined in TypeScript:

```
// inquiry.ts
export class Inquiry {
  name: {
    first: string,
    last: string
  };
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  question: string;
}
```

My form component is as such:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { InquireService } from './inquire.service';
import { Inquiry } from './inquiry';

@Component({
  selector: 'inquire-form',
  templateUrl: './inquire-form.component.html'
})
export class InquireFormComponent implements OnInit {
  inquiryForm: FormGroup;
  inquiry = new Inquiry;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private inquireService: InquireService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.inquiryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': [
        this.inquiry.name.first, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(2),
          Validators.maxLength(50)
        ]
      ], ...
  }
}
```

The error I get when I hit my route is:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

When I log `this.inquiry.name` it is indeed `undefined`, but I'm not understanding why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You merely stated what the type signature of the `name` property is but haven't actually initialized it.

Comment: Hmm. Is it not initialized when I created the new Inquiry instance (above the constructor)?

Comment: As far as I understand, you just declared that an `Inquiry` object contains 4 properties, a `name` of type `{first:string,last:string}` and `email`, `phone`, and `question` of type `string`. None of the properties are explicitly initialized so they just have their default values (`undefined`).

Comment: I see. I'm new to Typescript. Should I / can I provide a default value of an empty string for those properties in the class definition? Or should I pass the default values in when I create the instance?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding why I have to provide a value for `name` but not the other properties.

Comment: It all depends on how you access the properties.  They all _should_ be initialized but it isn't a strict requirement.  In your particular case, you don't attempt to access properties of the others.  If you had `this.inquiry.email.length` somewhere, it would fail for the same exact reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that none of your properties on the `Inquiry` object are initialized so they're all the default value `undefined`.  And since the one that matters `name` isn't initialized, attempts to access any of its properties (`first` or `last`) will fail.

Either set it in a constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.name = {} as any; // too lazy to give first/last properties
}
```

or initialize it in the declaration:

```
class Inquiry {
    name = {} as {
        first: string,
        last: string
    };
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    question: string;
}
```

or if you want to explicitly keep the type in the declaration and not rely on type inference:

```
class Inquiry {
    name: {
        first: string,
        last: string
    } = {} as any;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    question: string;
}
```

Comment: Ah. The second example makes more sense. I'll give that a try as soon as I get back to my computer. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I implemented the second example and my formBuilder is working again. Thank you! Obviously I need to brush up on my TypeScript.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is necessarily a typescript thing, just general OOP. The difference here is that you're describing a pattern of an object and not giving it an explicit name. You declared a variable/property to an object with certain properties.  But you still need to initialize that variable to some value as you would in say Java or C#.

Comment: Gotcha. It's been about 10 years since I've worked with C# :)